# Record all request uris/methods/response codes for Google Drive Java Client Library

Tags: google-drive-api, google-client, client-library

I'm using the google client library to access the Google Drive API. I'd like to custom log all the request URI's, the request method as well as the response codes. Is there a built in mechanism to do this with the google client library?

Ideally, I could use the API as I am now and not have to modify each request but maybe add some sort of interceptor to the Drive object itself where I can record this data on every request that goes through this Drive service.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that is exactly what you want but you could modify the log level of the API client in logging.properties

```
com.google.api.client.level = FINEST
```

Comment: Sorry when I said "log" I actually meant get the data and store it somewhere (maybe a DB or a file) - not necessarily logging it to console.

Comment: Depending on the logging framework you may be able to configure it to log to a persistent source.